# Execute Powershell script on older version of PS

Tags: powershell

I'm working on PowerShell 5.0 and i want to start a script on another server running PowerShell 2.0.

I tried to use `Invoke-Command` but it doesn't work, do you know if there is a solution to "emulate" the script on my PC ?

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-printer} -ComputerName server
```

*The term `Get-Printer` is not recognized as the name of a CmdLet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.*

Comment: No, `Get-Printer` does not exist as a cmdlet on any PC that is still running powershell v2.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it's easier to use the parameter `ComputerName`. It will connect to the remote machine and retrieve the printers on its own.

```
Get-Printer -ComputerName 'Server'
```

Another option would be to use `WMI`:

```
Get-WmiObject -ClassName 'Win32_Printer' -ComputerName 'Server'
```

And if you really want to use `Invoke-Command`:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'Server' -ScriptBlock {
    Get-WmiObject -ClassName 'Win32_Printer'
}
```

The last option will execute the code on the remote machine. It will most likely work because the CmdLet `Get-WmiObject` is present in the older version of PowerShell on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer i know the other way with the -ComputerName,
I want to use Invoke-command in priority.

I'll try Get-wmiObject